# Is it possible? xAxis categories with Json?

Tags: json, highcharts

Highcharts;

I'm trying to change categories dynamically in a column chart with a json. Something like this...

```
[{y:1,"other":"other","category":"namecategory"}....]
```

..

```
  xAxis: {
                    categories: this.category,
                    maxZoom: 1
                },
```

Is it possible?

Thanks. :D

Comment: you need to post some code. you can parse json as a javascript object, change the parameter you want to modify and re-render your chart.

Comment: maxZoom is depracated, so I advice to use afterSetExtremes and check range.

Comment: I see in api, and then I replace by minRange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe you can try it something like this:

```
var jsonData = [{
    "y": "1",
        "other": "other",
        "category": "namecategory1"
}, {
    "y": "2",
        "other": "another",
        "category": "namecategory2"
}];

// var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var categories = new Array();
for (var p in jsonData) {
    categories.push(jsonData[p].category);
}
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically load your categoreis i.e by json or other and then use [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories) which allows to change categoreis, dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set categories as an **Array** of primitive js types such as number or string.

Example:

```
categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
```

As it is mentioned here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories :
"If categories are present for the xAxis, names are used instead of numbers for that axis."

Maybe, when you mention JSON are you talking about Object Literals? (because "y" key in your sample is not quoted.)

**In fact , you CAN use an Array of Object Literals. But they will be displayed as "[Object]" in the xAxis.**

An object literal is a pair of curly braces surrounding zero or more name/value
pairs. An object literal can appear anywhere an expression can appear:

```
var empty_object = {};
var stooge = {
first_name: "Jerome",
last_name: "Howard"
};
```

The quotes around a property’s name in an object literal are optional if the name would be a legal
JavaScript name and not a reserved word.

Maybe you can pre-process your JSON data an build an Array to be used in categories.

Comment: this way I already know. What I want is to 'fill' the chart data and categories with one json file if it is possible.

Comment: are you going to use a specific 'key/value' contained in your JSON file to be displayed in xAxis? Give us a sample of your JSON file.

Comment: Now with y quoted.

`[{""y"":1,"other":"other","category":"namecategory"}]`

Comment: Is the answer below helpful? If not, give more details of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Now it works, but I can't do like I imagine, something like...

`options.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories)`, before instantiate the chart.